# How much can an intelligent item with the fly ability carry?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, flight, encumbrance, intelligent-magic-items

One of the special abilities you can give an [intelligent item](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/intelligent-items/) is the ability to fly:

> Item can [fly](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fly), as per the spell, at a speed of 30 feet

I've always assumed that intelligent items have no Dexterity, Strength and Constitution scores. However a strength score determines your carrying capacity, so how much can it carry?

Answer (score 1):

All creatures can carry a certain weight (light load) according to their strenght score. The weight they can carry explicitly excludes theyr own weight and a dress, so even with no str the sword can move and fly (but it can't carry anything more than a dress).

Dexterity means the sword does not move. It has no moving parts, it is rigid. But it can still move around, just as anyone with a flight speed given by some magic that does not involve wings can.